# Please clarify Empowered Shot feat touch attack option?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, psionics

> #### Empowered Shot [Psionic]
>
> **Prerequisites:** Point-Blank Shot.
>
> **Benefit:** As long as you maintain psionic focus, the range of your ranged weapons doubles. You may expend your touch attack)[sic] to ignore any penalties for range increment for that single attack. That attack still has its range doubled as if you were maintaining psionic focus.

Does **expend your touch attack** mean you count that single ranged attack at double the range as a touch attack (attack bypasses armor, including shields and natural armor).

Here is how the feat is described in the Psionics Expanded: Advanced Psionics Guide

> Empowered Shot [Psionic] You can empower your ranged attacks, sending
> them farther. Prerequisites: Point-Blank Shot.
>
> Benefit: As long as you maintain psionic focus, the range of your
> ranged weapons doubles. You may expend your psionic focus as part of a
> ranged attack (but not ranged touch attack) to ignore any penalties
> for range increment for that single attack. That attack still has its
> range doubled as if you were maintaining psionic focus.

So does this mean (example: shuriken 10' range would be now 20') . So does that mean using psionic focus Shuriken can be thrown at it maximum range increment at no penalties some 100'?

Comment: I strongly suspect that there was a typo or other error made when adding this to PFSRD, because of the weird extra parenthesis that appears in the benefit, and because this text basically doesn’t make sense. I am investigating this theory. Please note the [Fell Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/fell-shot-psionic/) feat, however, which **does** make your ranged attack a touch attack (i.e. ignores armor and shields).

Comment: Yeah looks like "psionic focus as part of a ranged attack (but not ranged " just got accidentally deleted/omitted.

Comment: Added feat as described in the Psionics Expanded: Advanced Psionics Guide. So does this mean (example: shuriken 10' range would be now 20') . So does that mean using  psionic focus Shuriken can be thrown at it maximum range increment at no penalties some 100'?

Answer (score 4):

The *Advanced Psionics Guide* version of the feat is correct; ignore the SRD version. Looks like somebody accidentally a few words. If you are interested in having your ranged attacks count as touch attacks, and ignore armor and shields, see the [Fell Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/fell-shot-psionic/) feat.

> So does this mean (example: shuriken 10' range would be now 20') . So does that mean using psionic focus Shuriken can be thrown at it maximum range increment at no penalties some 100'?

Yes, that’s exactly what it means.

- The shuriken’s range increment is 10 feet, which is doubled to 20 feet due while you have psionic focus thanks to Empowered Shot.
- The [weapons rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/) add this bit:

  > A thrown weapon has a maximum range of five range increments.

  So with Empowered Shot and psionic focus, a shuriken can be thrown at most 100 feet. This would incur a –10 penalty on the attack in most cases, however.
- Expending your psionic focus allows you to ignore range penalties, so that –10 penalty goes away. Empowered Shot explicitly indicates that the range increments are still doubled for this attack.
- Note that any subsequent attacks (e.g. during a full attack) do not benefit, so they still take range penalties, and furthermore (assuming you do not have any second psionic focus, e.g. from a Deep Body or Psicrystal Containment feat) your range is no longer doubled, so you could not attack any target beyond 50 feet.

Comment: When the feat says, "As long as you maintain psionic focus, the range of your ranged weapons doubles," why must that mean range *increment* rather than *maximum* range?

Comment: Would that not be because it refers to the range property of a weapon, which define its range increment?

Comment: @royalmurder I… don't know how to address directly that negative question, but I get your point. `;-)` The description of a weapon's range entry says, "Any attack at more than this distance is penalized for range," so, yeah, that *does* cover this feat, but that's *awfully* precise in a game that's usually much sloppier.